# >2GB file upload $_FILES["file"]["size"] negative number

Tags: php, php-5.4

I am getting at >2 GB file upload negative number at $_FILES["file"]["size"].

However file uploads fine and filesize() also returns correct size. But how to solve $_FILES to return correct value?

I have read about the issues at some old versions of php, they also had an error at returning negative number at filesize(), but this seems fine now. Did they just forget to fix $_FILES? Dont you know if its fixed on php 5.5.0 ?

PHP: 5.4.16
OS: Debian Squeeze 6.0.7 x64
Webserver: Nginx 1.2.7

Comment: What does `sprintf('%u', $_FILES['file']['size'])` give?

Comment: See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44522

Comment: Will recommend you using FTP functions.

Comment: Jack: 18446744072347431725, Maerlyn: I've seen this bug at php.net, but Submitted 2008 and modified in 2012, few patches were done to 5.2 php and then nothing new till today? :/

Comment: Atul, yes I know, thanks, will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

whatever the problem is, you can probably work around it **up to 4GB** like this:

```
$file_size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$true_size = $file_size >= 0 ? $file_size : 4*1024*1024*1024 + $file_size;
```

But, as you said, `filesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);` is the safest way to go (will work above 4GB too).

Comment: Indeed. This bug is due to the size being stored in a signed 32 bits integer. The largest storable value is 2^31 (32 bits minus the sign bit). When the value is overflown the sign bit gets set and the size gets negative. The trick given by Walter emulates the correct behavior by exploiting the int's sign, and it is forward compatible.

Comment: Tthanks for your reply. I think I ended with filesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); this works fine.